# Which mountains in the Lower Mainland, BC can be ascended by private car in the summer?

Tags: automobiles, mountains, vancouver, british-columbia

Like Cypress Mountain (via Cypress Bowl Rd.) and Mount Seymour (via Mt. Seymour Road), what satisfies these criteria:

1. They must be located within the following (demarcated) area: [image]
2. My grandparents wish to drive upward to enjoy scenery at higher elevations. So [local maxima](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/110492/50720), and not summits (i.e. global maxima), suffice.
3. The roads must begin south of these mountains (e.g. West or North Vancouver, Coquitlam, Mission, Harrison Mills), to minimise driving time from Vancouver.

Comment: Not by car, but you can get a cable car up Grouse mountain.

Comment: Another non-answer but Whistler/Blackcomb is not a long drive (maybe 90 minutes under good conditions) from Vancouver and has cable cars and a chair lift to the summit from the village during summer. Around $50 person, very scenic.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, 
all of what is shown in the map. I removed the redundant copy.

Comment: @pnuts Yes, `elevated vantage point accessible by road vehicle`. In fact, Cypress Bowl Rd. has a few of these.

Comment: Voting to close as WANTA as this request is too specific to be of much help for other travellers and "constructing itineraries" is head-on [WANTA](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1445/32134).